# Are 4e monsters compatible/level equivalent without adjustment in Gamma World?

Tags: dnd-4e, gamma-world, gamma-world-7e

I plan on running a brief Gamma World campaign with my group, and I am wondering if 4E monsters are compatible between systems without any sort of level adjustment? From a quick perusal, it seems like PCs are considerably more powerful than 4e characters of equivalent level: adding level rather than 1/2-level to rolls, alpha mutations/tech cards, major critical bonuses, hit points are restored with a short rest, etc. At the same time they are much less "survivable": the only reliable healing is through second wind, no specialized leader roles. To be equally challenging should I treat the party as a few levels higher when building an encounter with 4e monsters? Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**D&D 4E and Gamma World encounters can be used almost as is in the other game**

Characters in Gamma World dish out more damage, and are a bit more brittle than their 4e equivalents, but that just makes fights a bit more swingy and a run a bit faster.

**D&D 4E and Gamma World monsters can be used almost as is in the other game**

Comparing some monsters in the two games

**Gamma Word**

```
Porker Marauder 100XP
Level 1 Soldier, 29 HP, AC 17, NADs 16, 13, 12
Melee Basic: +6 vs AC, 2d6+1 damage

Sep Thresher 200XP
Level 5 Brute, 75 HP, AC 17, NADs 18, 16, 16
Melee Basic: +10 vs AC, 2d6+6 damage
```

**D&D 4E, Monster Vault**

```
Dwarf Clan Guard 100XP
Level 1 Soldier, 33 HP, AC 17, NADs 15, 15, 13
Melee Basic: +6 vs AC, 1d10+3 damage

Ravenous Ghoul 200XP
Level 5 Brute, 76 HP, AC 17, NADs 18, 17, 15
Melee Basic: +10 vs AC, 3d8+4 damage
```

Also see [this Extreme Reskinning article](http://slyflourish.com/extreme_reskinning_young_white_dragon_into_cyborg_assassin.html) for an example of reskinning a white dragon from the Monster Vault into a cyborg assassin for Gamma World.